# Compress Filter + MVC + Yahoo YSlow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gzip

I've been using Yahoo's YSLOW to try and make my pages go faster at [AgentX](http://www.agentx.co.nz)

I am using the below compress filter.  When I run the site through visual studio YSLOW says that all the files are compressed and I get an A when I view the live site it gets an E and says my files need to be gzipped.  Can anyone explain?

```
    public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter,
                CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, 
                CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use Firebug or Fiddler and post the Request and Response data, to your live web page?

Comment: Okay this actually works fine from home and not work.  At work we go through web marshall proxy so maybe this is why.  Anyhow I'm happy to close this questions.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the same mechanism on my site:

http://www.avantprime.com/articles/view-article/7/compress-httpresponse-for-your-controller-actions-using-attributes

I suggest using fiddler to see if your response from the live site is actually compressed and then you can determine if there is something up with YSlow or with your code.

I suggest that you run google pagespeed also http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/. This does the same job as YSlow but made by google. Different algorithms for some things.

DaTribe

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Production on IIS 6?  Perhaps this can help.  [ASP.NET MVC compression options in IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649440/asp-net-mvc-compression-options-in-iis6)