# Why are my pages still not gzipped?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, compression

With the help of YSlow I'm trying to tune my pages a bit.
I thought it would be little effort for big gain to have my pages compressed.
After trying everything from [here](http://beta.orcsweb.com/articles/iis_compression_6.0.aspx), [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000059.html), [here](http://blowery.org/httpcompress/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649440/asp-net-mvc-compression-options-in-iis6) YSlow is still showing my pages are nog compressed.

I'm using asp.net mvc 1.0 on IIS6.

With the following rules in my global.asax I make sure that my static content is not handled by MVC.

```
routes.Clear();
// Turns off the unnecessary file exists check 
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
// Ignore text, html, files.
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.txt");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.htm");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
// Ignore the content directory which contains images, js, css & html   
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
//Exclude favicon (google toolbar request gif file as fav icon which is weird)   
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.([iI][cC][oO]|[gG][iI][fF])(/.*)?" });
```

This will make sure that my js and css files are statically accessible.

These are the relevant snips of my metabase.xml

```
<IIsCompressionScheme   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/deflate"
        HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
        HcCreateFlags="0"
        HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
        HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
        HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
        HcDynamicCompressionLevel="9"
        HcFileExtensions="htm
            html
            txt
            css
            js
            mvc"
        HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
        HcPriority="1"
        HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
            dll
            exe"
    >
</IIsCompressionScheme>

<IIsCompressionScheme   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/gzip"
        HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
        HcCreateFlags="1"
        HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
        HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
        HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
        HcDynamicCompressionLevel="9"
        HcFileExtensions="htm
            html
            txt
            css
            js
            mvc"
        HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
        HcPriority="1"
        HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
            dll
            exe"
    >
</IIsCompressionScheme>
```

(meta: not sure if I should be putting this on SO or on SF)

Comment: I'm not sure what RO is?

Comment: Rack Overflow, the IT sister site of Stack Overflow. I keep forgetting what it's really called.

Comment: Rack Overflow sounds like a porn site, but it's not. I checked.

Comment: @Joseph: RO was a proposed but reject name for that very reason.  The site is actually ServerFault so I guess we would use SF as an acronym.

Comment: Yes, fixed it. Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that compression is extension related, you need to specify all the extensions that should get either static or dynamic compression.  You can probably see this by looking at the HcFileExtensions and HcScriptFileExtensions attributes respectively.

So with MVC shoe-horned into IIS6 where you don't necessarily have file extensions you will not be getting any compression for dynamic content.  IIS7 does things differently since it uses a list of mimeTypes to trigger compression.  IIS7 with integrated pipeline is where we're really expect to be placing MVC apps.  In IIS6 its possible but its a kludge and compression is one of the casualties.

**Edit**

For static content on IIS6 bear in mind that compression happens on a separate thread and triggered after the first request to resource,  the first request itself goes out uncompressed.  Subsequent requests for the resource should then be supplied using the compressed version.

Comment: My static content (javascript, css etc) is not handled by mvc and has regular extentions so I would guess it could benefit from the compression.
I updated OP to answer your remark.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones +1 for that edit, which was an "Ah-HA!" with light-bulb over the head moment.